# Solve the following equation: $\sqrt {\sin x - \sqrt {\cos x + \sin x} } = \cos x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, nested-radicals

Solve the following equation: 
\begin{array}{l}{\sqrt{\sin x-\sqrt{\cos x+\sin x}}=\cos x} \\ \text{my try as follows:}\\{\sin x-\sqrt{\cos x+\sin x}=\cos ^{2} x} \\ {\sin x-\cos ^{2} x=\sqrt{\cos x+\sin x}} \\ {\sin ^{2} x+\cos ^{4} x-2 \sin x \cos ^{2} x=\cos x+\sin x} \\ {\sin ^{2} x+\cos ^{4} x-2 \sin x \cos ^{2} x-\cos x-\sin x=0} \\ {\sin ^{2} x+\cos ^{4} x-2 \sin x\left(1-\sin ^{2} x\right)-\cos x-\sin x=0} \\{\sin ^2}x + {\left( {1 - {{\sin }^2}x} \right)^2} - 2\sin x\left( {1 - {{\sin }^2}x} \right) - \cos x - \sin x = 0\\ {\sin ^{2} x+\sin ^{4} x-2 \sin ^{2} x+1-2 \sin x+2 \sin ^{3} x-\cos x-\sin x=0} \\ {\sin ^{4} x+2 \sin ^{3} x-\sin ^{2} x-3\sin x-\cos x+1=0}\end{array}

Now i think it gets more complicated , any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do this in one period $[-\pi, \pi)$.

According to the equation, $\cos x = \sqrt \cdots \geqslant 0$, then $x \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. Also inside the square root, $\sin x \geqslant \sqrt \cdots \geqslant 0$, then  $x\in [0, \pi) \cup \{-\pi\}$. Thus $x \in [0, \pi/2]$ at least.

To be more exact, we consider
$$
\sin x \geqslant \sqrt {\sin x + \cos x},
$$ 
equivalently, 
$$
\sin^2 x \geqslant \sin x + \cos x. 
$$
But in $[0, \pi/2]$, $\cos x \geqslant 0$ and $\sin^2 x \leqslant \sin x$, thus
$$
\sin x \geqslant \sin^2 x \geqslant \sin x + \cos x \geqslant \sin x,
$$
which means all $\geqslant $ are $=$. The $=$ holds iff $\cos x = 0$ and $\sin x = 1$. Thus the only possible $x$ is $\boldsymbol {\pi/2}$.

Clearly $x = \pi/2$ is truly a solution to the equation, so the final solutions are 
$$
\boxed {2n\pi +\frac \pi 2, n \in \mathbb Z }\ .
$$

Answer (score 3):

We see that $\sin{x}\geq0$ and $\cos{x}\geq0.$

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{\sin{x}-\sqrt{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}},$ where $x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right].$

Thus, $$f'(x)=\frac{\cos{x}-\frac{\cos{x}-\sin{x}}{2\sqrt{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}}}{2\sqrt{\sin{x}-\sqrt{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}}}>0$$ for $\cos{x}-\sin{x}<0.$

But for $\cos{x}-\sin{x}\geq0$ we obtain:
$$f'(x)=\frac{4\cos^2x(\sin{x}+\cos{x})-(\cos{x}-\sin{x})^2}{4\sqrt{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}\sqrt{\sin{x}-\sqrt{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}}(2\cos{x}\sqrt{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}+\cos{x}-\sin{x})}$$ and
$$4\cos^2x(\sin{x}+\cos{x})-(\cos{x}-\sin{x})^2=4\cos^2x(\sin{x}+\cos{x})+2\sin{x}\cos{x}-1=$$
$$=4\cos^2x(\sin{x}+\cos{x})+2\sin{x}\cos{x}-\sqrt{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}\geq$$
$$\geq2\cos^2x(\sin{x}+\cos{x})-\sin{x}-\cos{x}=(\sin{x}+\cos{x})^2(\cos{x}-\sin{x})\geq0,$$
which says that $f$ increases.

But $\cos$ decreases, which says that there is unique $\alpha\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, for which our equation has root.

$\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a root, which gives the answer:
$$\left\{\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k|k\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$

Answer (score 2):

It can be seen that the radical of the form $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+..}}$ is undefined for $x<1$. Since $\sin{x}$ is on the interval $[-1,1]$. This means that it is only defined for $x=\arcsin(1)$. Or generalizing this, we get;
$$x=2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}, \tag{for n ∈ Z}$$

Answer (score 0):

In any solution, $\cos(x)$ is nonnegative, since it equals some square root.

In any solution, $\sin(x)$ is nonnegative, since the equation includes the square root of $\sin(x)$ minus some nonnegative quantity.

So $\cos(x)+\sin(x)\geq\sin(x)$, and therefore $$\sqrt{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}\geq\sqrt{\sin(x)}\geq\sin(x)$$
where the last inequality is because $\sin(x)\leq1$. And note that equality only holds if $\sin(x)=1$ or $\sin(x)=0$.

So $\sin(x)-\sqrt{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}\leq\sin(x)-\sin(x)=0$, and therefore $$\sin(x)-\sqrt{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}\leq0$$

In the equation, we take a square root of this expression. So it is not defined unless we have equality, which we noted is only possible if $\sin(x)=1$ or $\sin(x)=0$.

No solution can have $\sin(x)=0$, or else $\sin(x)-\sqrt{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}<0$, and we cannot take its square root in the equation.

Any $x$ with $\sin(x)=1$ implies $\cos(x)=0$, and such $x$ do indeed make a solution, by inspection.

So the given equation is equivalent to $\sin(x)=1$, and the solution set is $\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$.