# Solve the equation $\sqrt{\sin (x) - \sqrt{\sin(x) +\cos(x) }}=\cos(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

:
Solve the equation $\sqrt{\sin (x) - \sqrt{\sin(x) +\cos(x) }}=\cos(x)$

Comment: As far as I can tell, a purely algebraic approach will lead to $\sin x$ being a root of a degree 8 polynomial out of which only 2 of the roots are rational.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7Ba-x%2Ca%5E2-%28y-b%29%2Cb%5E2-%28y%2Bx%29%2Cx%5E2%2By%5E2-1%7D%2C%7Ba%2Cb%2Cx%2Cy%7D%5D  So, I would guess that any reasonable solution would have to make use of the limited range of $\sin x, \cos x$ and/or positivity of square roots at some point.

Comment: This has been discussed in [Q. 3278414](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278414). Doing it non-algebraically is the way.

Answer (score 2):

From $\sqrt{\sin x - \sqrt{\sin x + \cos x}} = \cos x$, as the LHS is non-negative, we must have $\cos x \geqslant 0$.  It is also easy to see that we must have $\sin x \geqslant 0$ for the LHS to exist.

Consider then the case $\cos x > 0$.  This gives $\sin x + \cos x > \sin x$ and hence $\sqrt{\sin x + \cos x }> \sqrt {\sin x} > \sin x \implies $ the LHS is the root of a negative number.  Hence this cannot hold true.

The only remaining case is $\cos x = 0$, which in fact satisfies the equation with $\sin x = 1$, so we must have $x = \dfrac{\pi}2 + 2n \pi $ with $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sin{x}=t$.

Thus, $0<t\leq1$ and we need to solve
$$t-\sqrt{t+\sqrt{1-t^2}}=1-t^2$$ or for $t^2+t-1\geq0$
$$(t^2+t-1)^2=t+\sqrt{1-t^2}$$ or
$$(1-t)(1-2t-3t^2-t^3)=\sqrt{1-t^2},$$ which gives
$t=1$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k$, where $k$ is an integer number or

for $1-2t-3t^2-t^3>0$ $$(1-t)(1-2t-3t^2-t^3)^2=1+t,$$ which is impossible because
$0<1-t<1$ and $0<1-2t-3t^2-t^3<1$, but $1+t>1.$